# Chrome not executing cgi script

Tags: google-chrome, refresh, cgi-bin, awstats

Is there any specifics or peculiarities in regards to chrome and getting it to exec a cgi(pl) script.

I've added awstats to my apache2 server and it works fine in Firefox and IE. However when I view it in chrome, it's almost as if it's caching the request.

It simply displays the old data no matter how many times I click refresh. I've tried it in a new tab, but I can't seem to get it to fire the script.

Any suggestions?

```
<Location "/awstats">
    AuthName "Private Site"
            AuthType basic
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htusers
            Require valid-user
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.0.0/24
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

For those familiar with awstats, I can select different months, and it seems to execute once. But after that, that month is cached to and won't refire. It really seems like it's caching and won't actually refresh.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at (thanks plokuc)

https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome

It seems Chrome has some sort of bug in it's refresh mechanism. The only solution at the moment seems to be manually clearing the cache and reloading the page, or running in incognito mode.

Bug report:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122